# how to dynamically set custom conn string for db context?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following db context which was auto-genned through the wizard in VS:

```
MyEntities : DbContext
```

When I go to the auto-genned definition, I see the following constructor defintion:

```
public MyEntities() : base("name=SecurityApiEntities")
{
}
```

I need to be able to set the connection string dynamically. How can I go about doing this? I don't see a way to do this off hand described in this url:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592674(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: That value you pass to the base constructor can be a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can not keep the connection string in the config file you can do something like this:

```
var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

// use your ADO.NET connection string
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = conString;

// Set the Metadata location.
entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl";
var dbContext = new DbContext(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

To avoid having to do this every single time you want a DbContext you can create a Factory class and method that will return you the DbContext based off of the connection string passed in. Or create a Partial Class that extends your DbContext with a Create function.